# Math formula for Exercise 2.2 - Daniel Liang

Tags: java

this is my first post here.

I've been searching around for an answer to one exercise i was trying to do in the Introduction to Java Programming book by Daniel Liang (10th edition).

I think most of my code is correct, but my answers differ from the books console example. I used the math formulas the book told me to use, and when I enter the same numbers in the console, my answer is not the same.

More specific it asked me to use this formula to calculate the area: area = square root(3) / 4 (length of sides)^2

I might have done something wrong with adding that formula, but searching around people kept suggesting using the same thing (Math.sqrt(3))

Here is my code, any help is appriciated:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create new scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter length and height of the Equilateral triangle
        System.out.print("Enter length of the sides" +
        " and height of the Equilateral triangle: ");

        double lengthOfSides = input.nextDouble();

        // Calculate the area & display to user
        double area = (Math.sqrt(3) / 4) * (Math.pow(lengthOfSides, 2));
        System.out.println("The area is: " + area);

        //Calculate the volume & display to user
        double volume = area * lengthOfSides;
        System.out.println("The volume of the Triangular prism is: " + volume);

        input.close();      

    }

}
```

Forgot to add what I get and what the book get:

I get
Enter length of the sides and height of the Equilateral triangle: 3,5
The area is: 5.304405598179686
The volume of the Triangular prism is: 18.565419593628903

The book:
Enter length of the sides and height of the Equilateral triangle: 3,5
The area is: 3.89
The volume of the Triangular prism is: 19.48

Comment: Does the formula state that you need to multiple the result of `square root(3) / 4` by the result of `lengthSides ^ 2`. If it does then you have implemented it correctly, if it doesn't then please say exactly what the formula says so we can work it out

Comment: I just double checked the area with a calculator: √3÷4×3.5² = 5.304405598 Can you double check the answer in the book, maybe there was a typo somewhere?

Comment: And just to be sure myself, the [formula](http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_equilateral_triangle.htm) is correct too

Comment: I just checked the book, it does not state that I need to multiple the result of square root(3) / 4 by the result of lengthOfSides ^ 2. How do i go about entering the code without the multiplier then? simply removing it causes a syntax error as it's expecting something there it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the inputs that the book is giving. The formula works if you use '3' as an input instead of '3,5'.

`(sqrt(3) / 4) * ( 3 ^ 2) = 3.89711431703`

You should make your program ask for the input of the length of sides, not the length of sides and the height of the triangle.

If you need to you can ask for the height of the triangle on a different scanner input.

Comment: That's why I didn't understood the volume formula here ! Nice catch.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eddie. However the example in the book inputs 3,5 and gets 3.89 as the area. I tried what you said about changing my input to 3, the area fits with the example in the book if I do that, but the volume is now 11,69 instead of 19,48 like in the book. Did they do something wrong with taking the input as an integer instead of a double? And does that mean I have to edit the formulas somehow?

Comment: AxelH, the volume formula is the same as they told me to use for formulas in the book: volume = area * length. And I just catched that height thing aswell, it's not needed so I'll remove that and only ask for the lengths of the sides. I just figured since the book asked for it in the console example, that I should do the same. Thank you all for your input :)

Comment: I think we will need to see the exact text from the book to understand the problem here. If the volume is wrong have you checked that your volume formula is correct? Please update or post a new question if there are more errors.

Comment: @EddieCurtis I'm not at the university right now, so I don't have a scanner available to scan the page, so I took a photo with my phone of the exercise http://imgur.com/a/nS2U9 . Hope this can help to find out what I've done wrong :) Also, if i try to input "3.5" instead of "3,5" it returns an error with the scanner. Do you have any idea why that is happening? Thank you.

Comment: In that case I assume you are using a European computer where the Locale states that the `,` delimits decimals not `.`. That is fine, and it should be working for you. Therefore it looks like the book has a bad example. Firstly they shouldn't even mention the height if all they want is the side lengths. Secondly, the result should be 5.3 not 3.89 like you already calculated. The author has clearly got the wrong answer because they simplified 3.5 to 3 in their code. Your code and math are both fine and I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @EddieCurtis Thank you so much for helping me :)